# Number of PRs which have not been approved right away

Tags: github

I'd like to list all PR of the last 6 months in a Github repository which have not been approved right away. Where was some sort of discussion during the code review. Is this possible? How?

Bottom line: I want to see if team members actually do a code review in this project or just wave PRs through.

Comment: This would be something to look up on github's support. Remember, git itself has no knowledge of pull-requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [advanced search syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-by-number-of-comments) on GitHub.

You need to use the following syntax on the PR page of Github in the filter field. Example:

[image: Screenshot of the form field]

To get all pull request with a discussion, you can filter them by their comment count:

```
is:pr is:closed comments:>0
```

You can combine that with the `created` filter to search for everything after a certain date:

```
is:pr is:closed comments:>0 created:>2017-11-25
```

For each of these searches, the number of open and closed issues is displayed in the "header" above the list of pull requests.

If this does not get you what you need, take a look at [GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/).